# What is this little cedar-like plant/tree?

Tags: trees, cedar

I believe this to be some kind of cedar (tree or bush), but would love to know which. Is it an actual cedar tree that could end up as a very large cedar tree? Or is it some kind of cedar scrub that will end up more like a plant?

It's about 12" tall at the moment. It was very prickly at first, as I mowed it down a few times ([see this other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/51022/what-is-this-prickly-plant-with-photo)), but the more it grows, the softer it feels.

I'm in Northern Ohio.  Any ideas, and if so, how can you tell?

[image]

**Update:** It now looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an Eastern Red Cedar (*Juniperus virginiana*), a native to Ohio. These are slow-growing trees that can get very tall and are not true cedars, although their wood has a pleasing scent. Note that the eventual form of the plant is variable - some specimens grow into a strongly narrow "classic pine tree" shape (called "fastigiate"), while others are much more pyramidal and some become chubby and short. Based on the current shape of your tree, I suspect that it will be in the pyramidal or fastigiate form. In any case, they are extremely easy trees to grow - essentially, do nothing and they'll grow just fine. They are also long-lived - the oldest tree known is over 900 years old.

This [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_virginiana) has more information about the tree.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You will not be able to grow apples in the area as when it gets large ,a fungus -cedar/apple rust, will like show up. The fungus does not bother the cedar.  I am very familiar with them from MO, AR, and TX. I would rather chose a tree from a shop. In that area Blue Spruce would be very attractive.

Comment: @blacksmith - There are many varieties of apples that are resistant to cedar-apple rust (https://apples.extension.org/table-of-apple-cultivar-susceptibility-to-cedar-apple-rust/). Also, spruces are susceptible to needle cast disease, which is in Ohio, making spruces a bad choice for the long term. (https://u.osu.edu/ornamentaldiseasefacts/nursery/rhizosphaera-needle-cast/what-is-it-what-to-do-about-it/)

Comment: It has been awhile since I tried to grow apples in MO. And spruce can get spider mites  but they can be sprayed. Eastern White Pine ?